# Objective-C access to counter from another class

Tags: objective-c

I´m new with objective-c and i have a question. I don´t understand where is my mistake.

The most time the counter tells me that the value is 0.

I have a game class, where is a counter. After a while when the Game stops the screen switch to the End class. And in the End class i want to print out the score. But it does not work.

```
Game.h    
@interface Game : CCLayer
{
  int counter;
}    
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) int counter;    
+(int)returnCounter;    
@end  
Game.m    
@implementation Game    
@synthesize counter;    
-(void)methodForMyCounter{
  counter++;
}
    +(int)returnCounter{
return counter;
} 
End.h    
End.m    
@implementation    
-(void)getCounter{
  //here i want to print out the counter    
}
```

Comment: Get a pointer to the other class's instance.  Use that to access the counter property.

Answer (score 1):

The `counter` is a property of an instance of the `Game` class, so you either need to be able to access that instance, or move the counter to a location that is accessible to both the `Game` and `End` objects. I would do that latter.

Move `counter` to your app delegate and `@synthesize` it. Then you can use this anywhere you want:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
int counterValue = [appDelegate counter];
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the +(int)returnCounter with -(int)returnCounter and call the returnCounter Method from your instance!

```
Game.h

@interface Game : CCLayer
{
  int counter;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int counter;

-(int)returnCounter;

@end


Game.m

@implementation Game

@synthesize counter;

-(void)methodForMyCounter{
  counter += 1;
}

-(int)returnCounter{
return counter;
}



End.h
@interface End : NSObject
{
  Game *_game;
}

End.m

@implementation

-(int)getCounter{
  if(!_game) {
    _game = [[Game alloc] init];
    //[_game retain] //if your are not using ARC
  }
  NSLog(@"%s %d or %d", __FUNCTION__, [_game returnCounter], _game.counter)
  return [_game returnCounter];

}
```